# How to concatenate variable in string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, concatenation

I am using this

```
var abc = jQuery('#pl_hid_addon_name').val(); 
alert(abc);

var atLeastOneIsChecked = jQuery('input[name="addon-"'+abc+']:checked').length ;
alert(atLeastOneIsChecked);
```

But it not worked
It should be after concatenate like below

```
var atLeastOneIsChecked = jQuery('input[name="addon-base-bar2[]"]:checked').length;
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
var atLeastOneIsChecked = jQuery('input[name="addon-"'+abc+']:checked').length;
                                                    ^
                                                    |
```

You used the closing " at the wrong place

```
var atLeastOneIsChecked = jQuery('input[name="addon-'+abc+'"]:checked').length;
                                                           ^
                                                           |
```

Answer (score 2):

Concatenate like this:

```
var atLeastOneIsChecked = jQuery('input[name="addon-'+abc+'"]:checked').length ;
```

Comment: The `name`'s value will break the selector if there's any special characters like `[`, because you've removed quoting.

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
var atLeastOneIsChecked = jQuery("input[name='addon-"+abc+"']:checked").length ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried some of the proposed above methods. However, no one was useful to me. After looking some information, I found the property attribute in jQuery (prop()). 
And that one works for me, the code is the following:

In my JSF file, I had the following code.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="asignacion" value="#{contratosBean.asignacion}">
<f:selectItems value="#{contratosController.asignaciones}"
        var="item" itemLabel="#{item.lblAsignacion}"
        itemValue="#{item.idAsignacion}" />
<f:ajax onevent="showDialog()" />
```

JavaScript section:

```
function showDialog() { if($([id='formContrato:asignacion']").prop("selected",true).val() == 'X1') { alert("function X1"); }else if($("id='formContrato:asignacion']").prop("selected",true).val() == 'X2'){alert("function X2"); }else{alert("Other function");} }
```