# How to put iterated variable in a HTML inside jQuery function?

Tags: jquery

I have a function:

```
jQuery(function($) {
var scntDiv = $('#textfields');
var i = $('#textfields p').size() + 2;
var a = 0;
$('#addbutton').click (function() {
$('<p><input type="text" id="test_testbutton" name="test_testbutton[a][0]" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /><input type="text" id="test_testbutton" name="test_testbutton[a][1]" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /><a href="#" id="removebutton">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
                i++;
        a++;
                return false;
        });

$('#removebutton').live('click',function() { 
if( i > 2 ) {
$(this).parents('p').remove();
i--;
}
return false;
});
});
```

And what I'd like to achieve is to make 'test_testbutton[a][0]' a 'test_testbutton[0][0], test_testbutton[1][0], test_testbutton[2][0]...etc' with every iteration. You may laugh, but I'm seraching for any info about it since today morning and I couldn't find the exact example. When I "console.log" the variable everything works perfectly, but I don't know how to put a variable inside HTML...

Comment: duplicate of this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302941/how-to-concatenate-variable-in-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just concatenate the value into the string like so:

`'<p><input type="text" id="test_testbutton" name="test_testbutton['+a+'][0]" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /><input type="text" id="test_testbutton" name="test_testbutton['+a+'][1]" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /><a href="#" id="removebutton">Remove</a></p>'`

Comment: This is IT!! i tried to use '+a' but it gave me an error every time I used it, I wasn't aware that it's needed to add another + after a variable. Thank you!!