# Displaying table with class in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to append some values from jQuery in my HTML table

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready!");

  // on form submission ...
  $('form').on('submit', function() {

    console.log("the form has beeen submitted");

    // grab values
    valueOne = $('input[name="perfid"]').val();
   
    console.log(valueOne)

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/",
   datatype:'json',
      data : { 'first': valueOne},
      success: function(result) {
  console.log(result.result[0].userid);
       
  
  $('#result').html("<table class="table table-bordered responsive"><tr><td>" + result.result[0].hosts[0].filer + "</td><td>" + result.result[0].hosts[0].hostname + "</td><td>" + result.result[0].hosts[0].model + "</td></tr></table>");
  
       
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    });

  });

});
```

I am getting error as :
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list for the line :

```
$('#result').html("<table class="table table-bordered responsive"><tr><td>" + result.result[0].hosts[0].filer + "</td><td>" + result.result[0].hosts[0].hostname + "</td><td>" + result.result[0].hosts[0].model + "</td></tr></table>");
```

Can someone point out what is going wrong?
TIA

Comment: Use quotes appropriately when nesting inside each other. `$('#result').html('<table class="table table-bordered responsive"><tr><td>" + result.result[0].hosts[0].filer + "</td><td>" + result.result[0].hosts[0].hostname + "</td><td>" + result.result[0].hosts[0].model + "</td></tr></table>');`

Answer (score 1):

its all about quotes

```
$('#result').html('<table class="table table-bordered responsive"><tr><td>' + result.result[0].hosts[0].filer + '</td><td>' + result.result[0].hosts[0].hostname + '</td><td>' + result.result[0].hosts[0].model + '</td></tr></table>');
```

take a look at [How to concatenate variable in string in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302941/how-to-concatenate-variable-in-string-in-javascript)

Comment: I have tried this but I cannot get anything displayed with it.

The div tag with result class stays blank.

Comment: @Akki by using $('#result') that mean you have element with result id not class if its class you should use $('.result')

Comment: @Akki glad it helped .. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```
var table = $('<table/>').addClass('table table-bordered responsive');
var rows='<tr><td>' + result.result[0].hosts[0].filer + '</td><td>' + result.result[0].hosts[0].hostname + '</td><td>' + result.result[0].hosts[0].model + '</td></tr>'; 
$(table).append(rows);
$('#result').append(table);
```