# Jquery variable as Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is my code....

This works fine....

```
console.log($("#2524 option:contains('dist123')").length);
```

But this does not work...

```
var myname='#2524'; console.log($("myname option:contains('dist123')").length);
```

how can i fix this?

Comment: `$(myname+" option:contains('dist123')").length` concat string to get as var if you dont it is treated as a string equal to `myname` if you add `myname+"` it is treated as `#2524`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
console.log($("myname option:contains('dist123')").length);
```

Here myname is not a variable whose value is '#2524' but simply a string.
you need to use myname as a variable. You can acheive it with concatenation

ie.

```
console.log($(myname+" option:contains('dist123')").length);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
var myname='#2524'; 
console.log($(myname+" option:contains('dist123')").length);
```

you may need to take a look at: [How to concatenate variable in string in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302941/how-to-concatenate-variable-in-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log($(myname+" option:contains('dist123')").length);
```

That should do it. Better read on **concatenation** in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `console.log($(myname+" option:contains('dist123')").length);` instead of `console.log($("myname option:contains('dist123')").length);`
Here In your answer, Myname is treated as a string not a variable but if you add `myname+"` it is treated as #2524