# Using " and ' in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a class dinamically.But now when I try to use I cant seem the find a correct way to place the `' and "`;

```
$('.modal-content').append('<div class="modal-body step-' + key + '" data-step="'+key+'"></div>');


$("modal-body step-' + key").append(input);
```

> unexpected token

Comment: You have mismatched quotes in the selector of the second jQuery object. `'` should be a `"`, and the last `"` should be removed: `$("modal-body step-" + key).append(input);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Append to string variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288095/append-to-string-variable)

Comment: More appropriate duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302941/how-to-concatenate-variable-in-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Your concatination is wrong. It should be

```
$("modal-body step-"+ key).append(input);
```

No need of single quote at all inbetween. Or if you prefer single quotes, use them completely

```
$('modal-body step-' + key).append(input);
```

After you fix that, there is one more issue. Since you are having classes, you have to add `.` for selector.

Comment: this doesnt work (i added the dot in the beginning). it doesnt append the variable input and it shows in the console.

Comment: I think it's because it has multiple classes

Comment: Please choose to close instead of answering such question. String concatenation is a very basic problem which has answered many times.

Comment: @Rajesh There is another problem with class selector aswell ?

Comment: I'm trying to append something to a div with 2 classes. I cant append.

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ OP already has `$('.modal-content')` which means he is aware about selectors and this might be a typo.

Comment: @Rajesh Everything is typo, once you corrected it ;)

Comment: yes it's a typo. I need to append the input to the div with those classes.

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Nope. A typo is something where a selector on first line is proper and on second line is not. But anyways, lets not invest more time on this discussion.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
$('.modal-content').append('<div class="modal-body step-' + key + '" data-step="'+key+'"></div>');


$('.step-' + key).append(input);
```

unless you expect to have multiple `divs` with step+key.  semantically you should use `id` for the unique part anyway.

edit:  ok then do it like this, if you must:

```
$('.modal-content').append('<div class="modal-body step-' + key + '" data-step="'+key+'"></div>');


$('.modal_body.step-' + key).append(input);
```

[here is a link](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to tell you why you need the extra `.` in there.

here is the relevant example from that link:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>class demo</title>
  <style>
  div, span {
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="myclass">div class="notMe"</div>
<div class="myclass otherclass">div class="myClass"</div>
<span class="myclass otherclass">span class="myClass"</span>
 
<script>
$( ".myclass.otherclass" ).css( "border", "13px solid red" );
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have more classes with step+key. it needs to be on the body